# Modify C++ template type T to be "long T"?

Tags: c++, templates, types

Is there any way to double the precision returned by multiply (to avoid overflow)?

```
template<class T> class MyClass {
     T multiply (T a, T b) { return a * b; }
}
```

Something like:

```
long T multiply (T a, T b) { return a * b; }
```

So that whether 'int', 'long', or 'double' was given, a 'long int', 'long long', or 'long double' would be returned from multiply.

This is a general question. I'm working around it by using a double internally. But my question is whether there is any mechanism to promote a type to its "long" variant in C++?

Comment: It's probably better to just use `long long` as your `T` if you want to avoid overflow.

Comment: `long` is not a qualifier that can be applied to a type name; `long int` is an indivisible type name that happens to be spelled with the two keywords `long` and `int`.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use "long T". T is a template parameter and it can be whatever primitive type or instance of object you want to be, as you long * operator is override. In some case you can cast T to long.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that there's no guarantee that the `long` version of a type is any larger than the normal one. `long` and `long long` are both 64 bits on my system, for instance.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Uhm... what? Maybe because it won't compile? You cannot *add* `long` (or `unsigned`), to a type.

Comment: @AndyProwl: you can remove your comment, and I can then remove mine and then your comment to my comment and my comment to that one, not forgetting to add a comment notifying of the deletion... and we can loop indefinitely from there... (well, you can also drop all your comments and I will drop mine at once)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A possible solution is to define your own type trait:

```
template<typename T>
struct add_long { typedef T type; };

template<>
struct add_long<int> { typedef long int type; };

template<>
struct add_long<double> { typedef long double type; };

template<>
struct add_long<long int> { typedef long long int type; };

// And so on...
```

This is how you would use it in your class:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {
public:
    typedef typename add_long<T>::type longT;
    longT multiply (longT a, longT b) { return a * b; }
};
```

And here is a small test:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    MyClass<int> m;
    auto l = m.multiply(2, 3);
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(l), long int>::value, "Error!");
}
```

Comment: Depending on expected use, you might want to omit `type` from the generic template, or otherwise ensure that you get a compilation error if you try this with with a type that doesn't have a `long`er version and therefore will overflow anyway. For safety, you could then define the specializations with `int8_t` -> `int16_t`, `int16_t` -> `int32_t` and `int32_t` -> `int64_t` to ensure that you really are increasing the size at each stage. Ofc that's slightly less portable since those are optional types, but on the systems the code doesn't port to `multiply` can overflow, which is best avoided.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Indeed, good observation. It mainly depends on how `MyClass` is meant to be used

Comment: @SteveJessop: The `unsigned` part is covered by the "and so on" comment ;-)

Comment: @Andy: Brilliant! While this works perfectly for my limited application, it can also be extended as you and Steve note.

Comment: Dont you want `a` and `b` to still be T?

Comment: @LokiAstari: yes, `a` and and `b` are of type `T`. Only the return value is of type `longT` (since only it could overflow -- the user of the class presumably knows what he's doing when he chose type `T` to hold the data).

Comment: @SteveJessop: an extremely useful suggestion that I've combined with Andy's original answer in my solution. Your comment is right-on and I hope it is up-voted more to draw more attention to it.

Comment: @Rubistro Then if `a` and `b` are still `T`, don't forget to cast them (or at least one of them) to `longT` **before** multiplying, as otherwise the multiplication will be upcast to the larger type **after** overflowing.

Answer (score 4):

@Andy has the right answer, which works quite well. But for those who want a compile-time error if MyClass is instantiated with a type for which there is no 'long' value, I've combined it with @SteveJessop's excellent comment to give the following solution:

```
// --- Machinery to support double-precision 'T' to avoid overflow in method 'multiply' ---
// Note: uncomment typedef if don't want compile-time errors 
// when no "long" type exists
// ----
template<typename T>
struct add_long { /*typedef T type;*/ };

template<> struct add_long<int8_t>   { typedef int16_t  type; };
template<> struct add_long<int16_t>  { typedef int32_t  type; };
template<> struct add_long<int32_t>  { typedef int64_t  type; };
template<> struct add_long<uint8_t>  { typedef uint16_t type; };
template<> struct add_long<uint16_t> { typedef uint32_t type; };
template<> struct add_long<uint32_t> { typedef uint64_t type; };

template<> struct add_long<float>    { typedef double        type; };
template<> struct add_long<double>   { typedef long double   type; };
```

Example usage of 'longT':

```
template<class T> class MyClass
{
    // Note: a compiler error on the next line means that 
    //       class T has no double-precision type defined above.
    typedef typename add_long<T>::type longT;
public:
    longT multiply (T a, T b) { return longT(a) * b; }
}
```

Example Usage of MyClass:

```
MyClass<float> my;
printf("result = %lf\n", my.multiply(3.4e38, 3.4e38));
```

Comment: What about the lonely `long int` between all those `intX_t`s? What if `std::int32_t` is `typedef`ed to `long int`?

Comment: @ChristianRau: good catch. That was left over and has been removed.